# Linking the vsplit views of two different buffers?

Tags: split

How can I link the vsplit views of two buffers so that the lines from both files are always in sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the `scrollbind` option :

```
:set scrollbind
```

See : `:h scroll-binding` for further reference.